# MySQL: Updating data from one column to another using two matching columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mariadb

I'm trying to update columns based on two matching columns: `firms.id = investors.firm` and `investors.firm_role = "ceo"`, but the server keeps rejecting my syntax. I have tried `inner join`s, without `inner join`s, it's all really too complex for me, so I'm not sure what to do next.

```
UPDATE firms 
JOIN investors USING (firms.id = investors.firm) 
SET firms.ceo = investors.name
WHERE investors.firm_role = "ceo"
```

Error:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.id = investors.firm) SET firms.ceo = investors.name WHERE investors.firm_role =' at line 1

Comment: Change USING with ON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close with your syntax:

```
UPDATE firms 
LEFT JOIN investors ON firms.id = investors.firm
SET firms.ceo = investors.name 
WHERE investors.firm_role = "ceo"
```

Refer to [this](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/).

Comment: @Keanu73 If it solved your problem, you should accept the answer (green check mark on the left).

Comment: sorry, had to go out as soon as I saw your answer and couldn't really accept it because of the acceptance timeout.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn why do you use a left join over an inner join?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Syntax

`update patients set column_name="value" where (condition)`

for example im using c# and it goes

```
update patients set " + dgv.Columns[c].HeaderText + "='" + dgv.Rows[dgv.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[c].Value.ToString() + "' where idno='" + dgv.Rows[dgv.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

`UPDATE firms 
INNER JOIN investors ON firms.id = investors.firm AND investors.firm_role = "ceo"
SET firms.ceo = investors.name`